# Why has my GA Goal got four steps instead of three?

Tags: google-analytics

I set up a goal with a funnel on my website.  The intended path is:  Homepage to teacher page to contact page. Which is three steps.

The setup looks like this:

[image]

Which seems legit. But the funnel visualisation in Google Analytics is showing four steps:

[image]

What am I missing? I would expect this to show that 10 people had completed the goal rather than five?

The site, for reference is https://www.whitewaterwriters.com/

Comment: Which version or Google Analytics are you using?   Are you using the older Universal Analytics or the new Google Analytics 4?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller -  Universal Analytics

Comment: GA4 doesnt have goal funnels

Comment: Has the funnel been edited and the steps changed at some stage.. the changes wont be retroactive and if you are including a date range prior the edit then the data is going to be funky

Comment: @BronwynV that appears to be the answer! Thank you! (and feel free to write it up, because I'm not entirely sure of the *why*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the funnel has been edited at any stage, those changes will not be retroactive.
Therefore if you are looking at a date range of data, prior to that change being made, the old information will also appear.